# Filtering large volume of data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Will mongodb be fast enough to handle the following :

- large volume of data
- Filtered selection of data from this volume for ex. filtration by date within which another filtration based on a 2nd value is to be included

Comment: how large is large? MB, GB, TB or YB.

Comment: Use sharding if your data is TB. if your system is in the YB range then look at distributed hashtables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's Aggregation Framework is fast enough for large variety of tasks. In my project I'm doing aggregations on gigabytes of data and it works fine.